# Solution to display widgets based on the page height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am looking to display widgets on wordpress based on the height of the page. So a small page might see 3 widgets, where a long post would show 10 widgets.

I currently use a sticky sidebar but I'm looking to display more widgets based on the page height.

Answer (score 0):

Try to decrease the size of the widgets using HTML code in your page.